# Microsoft CVRF API

Tags: security, updates, cve

It has come to my attention that, starting from February 9, 2021,
[Microsoft Security Response Center](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2021/02/09/continuing-to-listen-good-news-about-the-security-update-guide-api/) has removed registrations requirements to their [CVRF API](https://msrcapi.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/msrc-public-api/).

That  could be a nice way to programmatically identify, download and apply security updates and, for example, provisioning fully patched systems.

That being the case, I was trying to identify, the latest cumulative update for a given Windows version, say 20H2, to be later downloaded
from [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com), which lacks a proper API.

Currently, I can just think of parsing the call:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/cvrf/2021-Feb'
```

Is there a more specific and reliable way?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a straightforward way to parse the JSON output. However, this sort of works:

```
$product = "Windows 10"
$version = "20H2"
 
$raw = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/cvrf/2021-feb' -Headers @{"accept"="application/json"}
$json = $raw.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$search = "$product*$version*x64-based*"
$prd = $json.ProductTree.Branch[0].Items.Items | where{$_.Value -like $search}
$prdID = $prd.ProductID
($prd | Out-String) | Write-Host
$json.Vulnerability.Remediations | where{$_.ProductID -eq $prdID} |
  %{echo $_.URL} | Sort-Object | Get-Unique | Select -Last 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code wouldn't work for me on newer platforms, but if you check if ProductID array is greater than 0 and select the 0th element, you can string compare properly. The where-object doesn't allow you to do this to my knowledge. So I put $rem in place and did nested loops of prdID and $rem inside of that. I'd paste the code but the rules to post code I can't figure out. Just PM me if any questions.